# Вылетает исключение fragment already active

Tags: java, android

Вылетает исключение в методе setArguments(Bundle). Я читал другие ответы на этот вопрос. Там говорили о удалении текущего фрагмента перед тем как начать работу с новым, но я так и не понял как это сделать в моем случае.
Заранее благодарю за помощь.
Код MainActivity:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements FragmentEventListener {


    FragmentTransaction transaction = null;
    ArrayList<Translate> translates = new ArrayList<Translate>();
    TranslatorFragment translatorFragment = TranslatorFragment.newInstance();
    HistoryFragment historyFragment = HistoryFragment.newInstance();

    private BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener mOnNavigationItemSelectedListener
            = new BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
            switch (item.getItemId()) {
                case R.id.navigation_translator:
                        transaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                        transaction.setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_FADE);
                        transaction.replace(R.id.constraintLayoutMain, translatorFragment);
                        transaction.commit();
                        return true;

                case R.id.navigation_history:
                        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
                        bundle.putParcelableArrayList("translations", translates);
                        historyFragment.setArguments(bundle);
                        transaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                        transaction.setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_FADE);
                        transaction.replace(R.id.constraintLayoutMain, historyFragment);
                        transaction.commit();
                        return true;

            }
            return false;
        }

    };

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        this.setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);

        BottomNavigationView navigation = (BottomNavigationView) findViewById(R.id.navigation);
        navigation.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener(mOnNavigationItemSelectedListener);

        transaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        transaction.setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_FADE);
        transaction.replace(R.id.constraintLayoutMain, TranslatorFragment.newInstance());
        transaction.commit();


        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowCustomEnabled(true);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);


        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) this.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.action_bar_layout, null);

        getSupportActionBar().setCustomView(v);
        getSupportActionBar().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.parseColor("#696969")));
        translates.size();

    }

    @Override
    public void setArrayListHistory(ArrayList<Translate> translates) {
        for (int i = 0; i < translates.size(); i++) {
            this.translates.add(0, translates.get(i));

        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если посмотреть исходный код метода `setArguments()` (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>click</kbd>), то там мы увидим описание, что данный метод должен быть вызван до того, как фрагмент будет приаттачен к активити. У вас он вызывается уже после.

Вы можете изменить ваш код следующим образом: добавьте в ваш метод `HistoryFragment.newInstance()` следующий код (нужно, чтобы на следующем шаге не получить NPE при обращении к аргументам):

```
setArguments(new Bundle());
```

И теперь вместо `historyFragment.setArguments(bundle);` делайте

```
historyFragment.getArguments().putParcelableArrayList("translations", translates);
```

Comment: Спасибо большое, вы крутой ;)